# I am having trouble while implementing multiple dialog with element plus and vue js 3

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vuejs3, element

Here is my Sidebar.vue

template part
[image]
script part
[image]

I want to open a dialog for one menu item
but now if i click a menu item, the dialog open for other menu item